# Sending a number between a parent and child component

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React by myself and have come across a problem. I want to transmit a number from a parent component to a child component. After clicking a button in the child, the child adds 3 to the number and sends it back to the parent component. The parent component then adds 100 to the number sent back to it and stores it ready to transmit to the child again.

```
class Parent2 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            msgFromOut: props.out,
        };
    }


    getChildMsg = (data) => {
        console.log("get the msg from child component data is ", data);
        this.setState({
            msgFromOut: 100 + data,
        });
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="parent">
                this is father
                <Child2 getMsg={this.getChildMsg} outerMsg={this.state.msgFromOut} />
                <h1>{this.state.msgFromOut}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Child2 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("child is getting", props);
        this.state = {
            msgFromFather: props.outerMsg,
        };
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState(
            {
                msgFromFather: this.state.msgFromFather + 3,
            },
            () => {
                this.props.getMsg(this.state.msgFromFather);
            }
        );
    };

    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>to father</button>;
    }
}

reactDom.render(<Parent2 out={1} />, document.querySelector("#root3"));
```

The output the first time I click the button is 104, but starting from the second click the number is only added to 3 instead of 103, which is what I was expecting.

Why is it behaving this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause constructor only run once when component was created, you need to update the state when `outerMsg` changed.

Or you can simply use `this.props.outerMsg` in child component.

```js
handleClick = () => this.props.getMsg(this.props.outerMsg + 3);
```

```js
class Parent2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      msgFromOut: props.out,
    };
  }

  getChildMsg = (data) => {
    console.log("get the msg from child component data is ", data);
    this.setState({
      msgFromOut: 100 + data,
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="parent">
        this is father
        <Child2 getMsg={this.getChildMsg} outerMsg={this.state.msgFromOut} />
        <h1>{this.state.msgFromOut}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("child is getting", props);
    this.state = {
      msgFromFather: props.outerMsg,
    };
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.msgFromFather !== this.props.outerMsg) {
      this.setState({
        msgFromFather: this.props.outerMsg,
      });
    }
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        msgFromFather: this.state.msgFromFather + 3,
      },
      () => {
        this.props.getMsg(this.state.msgFromFather);
      }
    );
  };
  //   handleClick = () => this.props.getMsg(this.props.outerMsg + 3);

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>to father</button>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent2 out={1} />, document.querySelector("#root3"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root3"></div>
```